# Responsive images / boxes in bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to put 4 boxes side by side. when I resize the screen, I want the boxes to turn fluid in the screen area. I have boxes A to D in the first row and A1 to D1 in the second (in large screens, 4 boxes in a row, in medium, 3, in small, 2 and so on...) When I resize the screen I can't put the A1 box below the A box. It always goes to the right.

Can you help me?
thanks.

here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap for Web Design</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A Tuts+ course">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="content">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento1.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">A</div>
<div class="events-name">DJ Smart Prec Tour 2015</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento2.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">B</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento3.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">C</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento4.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">D</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento1.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">A1</div>
<div class="events-name">DJ Smart Prec Tour 2015</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento2.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">B1</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento3.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">C1</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="events-box"><img src="images/evento4.jpg"/>
<div class="categoria">D1</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
.content{
    max-width:1130px;
    margin:0 auto;

    }

.events-box{
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    max-width:300px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #888888;
    padding:20px;
    }

.events-box img {
    z-index: 30;
    max-width:200px;
    height:auto;
}

.categoria{
    color:white;
    background:#333c4e;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    max-width:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:2px;
    }

.events-name{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top:10px;

    }
```

Comment: wrap all the elements in a root parent `div` with class `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am grasping what your intentions are, then you have the entire grid out of place. You should first open the main `bootstrap` contianer with div class `contianer` or `container-fluid`, then within the container you open a `row` class for the first 4 boxes A-D, then a second `row` class for A1-D1. and each box within the row will have a class `col-md-3` read `bootstrap's` documentation for a better understanding of the available sizes. below is an example of the first row with boxes A-D. Let me know if I miss understood your question.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">Box A</div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Box B</div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Box C</div>
         <div class="col-md-3">Box D</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: yes, @andre3wap. I forgot the tag 'row'. Thank you so much.